# attiny uart transmit fails

Tags: c, uart, attiny

I am trying to transmit a byte on the uart of an attiny2313 but the transmit hangs in the loop that waits until UDR is available.

I am using the internal 8MHz clock.
Uart configured for 9600baud 8bit 1stopbit

My init code is as following:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL 
#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600UL
#define USART_UBBR_VALUE ((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE << 4)) - 1) 

UBRRL = (uint8_t)USART_UBBR_VALUE;
UBRRH = (uint8_t)(USART_UBBR_VALUE >> 8); 
UCSRB = ((1 << TXEN) | (1<<RXEN));
UCSRC = ((1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0));
```

After init I enable global interrupts using sei().

Transfer:

```
while (!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
UDR = 'B';
```

It hangs on the while loop, when I remove power from the device, it finally breaks while loop on last moment and sents the B.

I have tried adding delay of 200ms after init but didn't work.

I use similar code for an atmega88 and this is working fine.
Anyone an idea why it stays in the while loop?

Comment: Show `UCSRA` defintion.  Idea: Insure it is `volatile`.

Comment: I am using winavr with avrstudio, the UCSRA is defined in the supplied headers. #define UCSRA   _SFR_IO8(0x0B)